# Sequential Reader/Writer but pararell ItemProcessor

Tags: spring-batch

In the spring batch I want to accomplish such task:

1. Read input object from a file, one object span through multiple lines. So this must be a sequential.
2. Do an action on an object. [time expensive, require call to another app]
3. Write to an output file.

Since 2) is most time expensive I want to pararell this.

[image]

example flow diagram

[image]

How to achieve this in Spring batch ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For every read in a spring-batch process will be called ,
May be do away with reader writer and processor concepts and use a tasklet step to achieve the same with your custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option I can think of is:

- Create an `ExecutorService` and inject it into the processor.
- In the processor, instead of return `T`, submits a task to the executor and returns instead a future of `T`.
- The writer get a list of futures. For each future, it gets its value (likely blocking for a while, at least for the first items) and does its thing.